# How to draw specific part of texture in fragment shader (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit, opengl-es-2.0

I have a node size of 64x32 and texture size of 192x192 and I am trying to draw the first part of this texture at the first node, the second part at the second node...

*Fragment shader* (attached to SKSpriteNode with texture size of 64x32)

```c
void main() {
    float bX = 64.0 / 192.0 * (offset.x + 1);
    float aX = 64.0 / 192.0 * (offset.x );
    float bY = 32.0 / 192.0 * (offset.y + 1);
    float aY = 32.0 / 192.0 * (offset.y);
    float normalizedX = (bX - aX) * v_tex_coord.x + aX;
    float normalizedY = (bY - aY) * v_tex_coord.y + aY;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_temp, vec2(normalizedX, normalizedY));
}
```

- `offset.x` - [0, 2]
- `offset.y`  - [0, 5]
- `u_temp` - texture size of 192x192
- [function to convert a value from [0,1] to, for example, [0, 0.33]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/281165)

But the result seems to be wrong:

SKSpriteNode with attached texture

[image: SKSpriteNode with attached texture]

SKSpriteNode without texture (what I want to achieve with texture)

[image: SKSpriteNode without texture]

Comment: *"But the result seems to be wrong"* - What is wrong with the result?

Comment: The same code can be written on one line: `gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_temp, (v_tex_coord.xy + offset.xy) * vec2(64.0, 32.0) / 192.0);`

Comment: Thanks for comments 
p.s I updated question

Comment: `v_tex_coord` is in range [0.0, 1.0], isn't it?

Comment: according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshader/creating_a_custom_fragment_shader), yes

Comment: I found that if I load texture from sprite atlas then I get result above, but if load same texture not from atlas, then I get correct result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a texture is in an altas, it's not addressed by coordinates from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` anymore.  The atlas is really one large texture that has been assembled behind the scenes.  When you use a particular named image from an atlas in a normal sprite, SpriteKit is looking up that image name in information about how the atlas was assembled and then telling the GPU something like "draw this sprite with `bigAtlasTexture`, coordinates `(0.1632,0.8814)` through `(0.1778, 0.9143)`".  If you're going to write a custom shader using the same texture, you need that information about where it lives inside the atlas, which you get from `textureRect`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture/1519707-texturerect

So you have your texture which is not really one image but defined by a location `textureRect()` in a big packed-up image of lots of textures.  I find it easiest to think in terms of `(0,0)` to `(1,1)`, so when writing a shader I usually do `textureRect` => subtract and scale to get to `(0,0)-(1,1)` => compute desired modified coordinates => scale and add to get to `textureRect` again => `texture2D` lookup.

Since your shader will need to know about `textureRect` but you can't call that from the shader code, you have two choices:

1. Make an attribute or uniform to hold that information, fill it in from the outside, and then have the shader reference it.
2. If the shader is only used for a specific texture or for a few textures, then you can generate shader code that's specialized for the required `textureRect`, i.e., it just has some constants in the code for the texture.

Here's a part of an example using approach #2:

```swift
func myShader(forTexture texture: SKTexture) -> SKShader {
  // Be careful not to assume that the texture has v_tex_coord ranging in (0, 0) to
  // (1, 1)!  If the texture is part of a texture atlas, this is not true.  I could
  // make another attribute or uniform to pass in the textureRect info, but since I
  // only use this with a particular texture, I just pass in the texture and compile
  // in the required v_tex_coord transformations for that texture.
  let rect = texture.textureRect()
  let shaderSource = """
  void main() {
    // Normalize coordinates to (0,0)-(1,1)
    v_tex_coord -= vec2(\(rect.origin.x), \(rect.origin.y));
    v_tex_coord *= vec2(\(1 / rect.size.width), \(1 / rect.size.height));
    // Update the coordinates in whatever way here...
    // v_tex_coord = desired_transform(v_tex_coord)
    // And then go back to the actual coordinates for the real texture
    v_tex_coord *= vec2(\(rect.size.width), \(rect.size.height));
    v_tex_coord += vec2(\(rect.origin.x), \(rect.origin.y));
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
  }
  """
  let shader = SKShader(source: shaderSource)
  return shader
}
```

That's a cut-down version of some specific examples from here:
https://github.com/bg2b/RockRats/blob/master/Asteroids/Hyperspace.swift